# Reading syslog-ng logs being sent to a remote server

Tags: syslog, syslog-ng

I have a Docker container which is sending syslog logs to logentries.com. This is working fine, but for times when logentries is down or delayed, I want a way to read logs generated in realtime inside the container.

I know I could just write the logs to a file, but I'd rather not do that because I very rarely need them, and also the storage is ephemeral since it's inside Docker.

Ideally there would be some way to read logs processed by syslog-ng, perhaps via the /dev/log socket?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a file destination with templated filenames and the [overwrite-if-older() option](https://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/reference-destination-file.html). That way you could store the logs only for a week or a day.

You could use the usertty destination, but AFAIK there is no console you could connect to in docker, and also usertty can be slow in syslog-ng (which might not be an issue if there are not so many logs on your host).

A third option is to use the disk-buffer of syslog-ng, that way syslog-ng stores the logs on disk if logentries is not accessible, and sends them when it is up again. However, disk-buffer will be available only in syslog-ng 3.8, which is not released yet (but you can compile the development version from the source from [GitHub](https://github.com/balabit/syslog-ng))

Regards, 
Robert Fekete